# filter attributes in select field with simple_form in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, simple-form

I have this select input with simple_form:

```
<%= f.input :board, :collection => Board.where(:user_id => current_user.id)%>
```

I want show in select field all boards where external attribute `:user_id` math with `current_user.id`

I want to make an exception in the select field results.

**I want the select field to show me the previous results except where board's title is equal to current_user's username sth like:**

```
<%= f.input :board, :collection => Board.where(:user_id => current_user.id).except(:title => current_user.title) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is the next query:

```
Board.where(user_id: current_user.id, :title.ne => current_user.username)
```